# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: credential identifier cannot be empty - Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

When trying to login using Firebase authentication with Google, the following error appears, after selecting the Google account:

```
07-02 18:30:56.356 9148-9148/com.xxx.yyy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.xxx.yyy, PID: 9148
             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: credential identifier cannot be empty
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzh(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential.<init>(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.account_link.SaveCredentialsActivity.onConnected(SaveCredentialsActivity.java:120)
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzl.zzm(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzk(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.zzsb(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzod.onConnected(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.onConnected(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznw.onConnected(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzj.zztp(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zztr(Unknown Source)
             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I am using the latest google Firebase API on Android

Comment: please add how you are trying to login the user.

Comment: I'm logging the user in using the firebase Auth UI library